# IP data lookup - C#

Tags: c#, web, automation, ip, lookup

Okay, so I've googled on several occasions regarding this, but each one suggests respectfully decent choices like : "Selenium" which works fine, but isn't use-able without firefox (or even within an API to my knowledge?).

I have this code :

```
 public byte[] GetFileViaHttp(string url)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                return client.DownloadData(url);
            }
        }
```

Then I also have this code :

```
        byte[] result = GetFileViaHttp(@"http://ip-lookup.net/");
        string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
        richTextBox1.Text = str;
```

Works fine, returns my IP's information, but I want to automate this with other IP addresses, rather than return my own. 
How would this be done ?
By this I mean, I want the API to take `txtBox1.Text` (IP) & print the details into `richTextBox1.Text` (Host/Country) ..

How could this be done ?

Comment: It can be done by passing the IP address along with your GetFileViaHttp call (most likely).  However, since it's an external resource you should probably check to see if they have any documentation that 1) tells you how to do it and 2) provides you with the legal right to use this API in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around the site and found a help document that details exactly what you want.

Simply pass the IP value as an unnamed query string parameter:

http://ip-lookup.net/?127.0.0.1

In your code:

```
byte[] result = GetFileViaHttp(string.Format("http://ip-lookup.net?{0}", ipAddress));
```

where you are injecting a string ip address as ipAddress.

You can find their help page [here](http://ip-lookup.net/help-lookup.php).  I looked for a legal agreement but I wasn't able to find one, so please use at your own risk and discretion.

**UPDATE:**

If you are getting 403s, you need to pass along a user agent header.  Your WebClient instance can be modified to include a header in the request.

```
public byte[] GetFileViaHttp(string url)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");    
        return client.DownloadData(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: @Hellooo123 I've modified my answer to solve your 403 question.

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you. Further question would be how to remove HTML information ? String.Replace would be tricky ..

Comment: You're welcome.  That's a great question for an entirely new thread.  I'd start by looking into Html Agility Pack and write a new question if you get stuck.